# Refering to html ID from external JS file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple html page with the following script at the top (in the header)

```
    function myCall(game) 
    {
        $( "#test" ).load( "InnerPageVideoContent.php", { 'game': game} );
    }
```

which is called when a button on the page is clicked.

What I wanted to do was move this into a .js file (that's in a "JS" sub folder).

So I created a .js file and put the function inside it. (I also changed the URL as the .js file is in a js folder

```
    function myCall(game) 
    {
        $( "#test" ).load( "../InnerPageVideoContent.php", { 'game': game} );
    }
```

Folder structure is

-JS (folder) - functions.js

-index.php

Now, when I call the function, the function is called ( I know it is called becuase if I put a break point in it, it gets hit) So I know it finds the function.

But nothing happens.  When the function was inside the actual index.php, it correctly loads the contents of "InnerPageVideoContent.php" to the "#test" id.

Is it failing because of the "#test" or the directory of the php page?

Many thanks for any help given

Comment: The path is relative to your index.php file, not the js file. So if you didn't move the php files, the path should stay the same

Comment: Paths in JS loaded externally are relative to the page that loaded it — therefore you don't have to change your URL.

Comment: the real question is what is the value of game and where does it come from, i imagine because you moved the function it its out of scope or something like that,and you are not calling load as you thought you were.

Comment: @Markai, you should post your answer as an answer in the section below, not as a comment on the question. Then the question won't show up as unanswered.